# What name would be given to a dumb, data class?

Tags: php, object, symfony

I'm writing a pretty simple email mime parser for an application I'm developing, and was thinking it'd be a good idea to create a dumb data class to make as 'an email' but as an object.

This is all well and good, and this might be a terrible question for SO, but alas, I am asking anyway. What would you call said dumb data class?

As I'm writing the project in Symfony 2.2 I thought using the word 'Entity'; as broad a term as it is, wouldn't make as much sense and could cause confusion because of Entities being used in DocTrine. So, what's the term that's used for this kind of thing? Just to store data and potentially use methods on it, like an entity, to format or retrieve other bits of information.

Comment: how about _ThisIsAveryDumbDataClass_?

Comment: How about DumbAndDumber ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the class just to pass data around, that's a DTO (Data Transfer Object from Java) in my opinion.So `EmailDto` could work
If you add methods to it i'd just use `Email` as the name of the class, just to describe what is.

Comment: Alright, but, this has to have a place in the directory structure. I like the idea of DTO, it makes sense. i.e. `Vendor\Package\DTO;` as the namespace, and `Email` as the class name. However, as you state, DTO may not be appropriate if methods are applied to the class. Can you make any other suggestions?

Comment: Chose to go with this one, after realising I'm not going to be needing to manipulate data on the object. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about calling it (the Germans among us are free to ROFL ;-) ):

POPO - Plain Old PHP Object

Comment: Haha, amusing, but would for sure cause confusion unfortunately. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generic names for classes are things like Object, Entity, Thing, Data, Class, Handler, etc. Descriptive names are really good to avoid confusion, though. YMMV

Comment: That's my issue, I need to avoid confusion. D: